# Thrift Make Error

Tags: cassandra, thrift

I can't compile thrift properly, when I use make, this is the output:

```
 make all
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/thrift'
Making all in compiler/cpp
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/thrift/compiler/cpp'
make  all-am
make[3]: Entering directory `/root/thrift/compiler/cpp'
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../..    -Wall -I./src -D     PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE_NP=PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE -MT thrift-thrifty.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/thrift-thrifty.Tpo -c -o thrift-thrifty.o `test -f 'thrifty.cc' || echo './'`thrifty.cc

In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/gthr-default.h:41,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.4/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/gthr.h:162,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.4/ext/atomicity.h:34,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/basic_string.h:41,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.4/string:53,
             from ./src/main.h:23,
             from thrifty.yy:33:
/usr/include/pthread.h:55: error: redefinition of 'PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE'
/usr/include/pthread.h:49: error: 'PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE' previously defined here
make[3]: *** [thrift-thrifty.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/thrift/compiler/cpp'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/thrift/compiler/cpp'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/thrift'
    make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any ideas? thanks :)

Comment: what os are you trying to compile thrift on?

Comment: http://blog.ibd.com/scalable-deployment/installing-apache-thrift-on-ubuntu-and-leopard/